# Copying Documents using openCMIS

Tags: alfresco, mule, cmis, opencmis

I am using Mule to access an Alfresco Server.  We are using OpenCMIS via the CMIS Connector.  I want to make a copy of a document in one folder and add it to another folder.  Or just copy the entire folder.  I need the copies to be independent of the originals, so that if the copies are static copies of the originals.

I suspect that in order to make copies I am going to have to go through the entire folder and copy not just the objects but also their relationships also.

Answer (score 2):

Document objects have a copy() method that lets you create an independent copy in a different folder. There is no copy method for folder hierarchies, though.

Comment: Thanks Florian!  What about relationships?  Does it copy those if there is a relationship between a document and another document?

Comment: That is repository specific. The copy() method is based on the CMIS createDocumentFromSource operation, which main focus it is to do the content copy efficiently inside in the repository.  But the repository might change everything else (permissions, properties, relationships, etc.) when it creates the new document.

I think in Alfresco the copy behavior is configurable.